# How can I invert the track of the slider?

Tags: angular, material-ui, angular-material

In our design we want the user to select a value between 0 and 20 and have the selected range be that value and up to 20. In the current implementation of the Angular Material slider component, the values from 0 and up to the value selected are highlighted (active track). Is it possible to reverse this?

I did consider trying to reverse the colors in the css, so that the inactive track would look like the active, but the inactive has some opacity applied to it, and I don't know how to adjust that. Anyway, that would be more of a hack.

Thankful for any insight on this.

I've looked at the API and couldn't find any way to reverse the track

Answer (score 1):

If you use a range-slider in the way

```
<mat-slider class="special" min="200" max="500" >
  <input value="300" matSliderStartThumb [(ngModel)]="value">
  <input value="500" matSliderEndThumb style="display:'none';cursor:'arrow'">
</mat-slider>
```

The last "thumb" not allow move

If you add **in your styles.sccs**

```
.special mat-slider-visual-thumb:last-child .mdc-slider__thumb-knob{
  display:none
}
```

You "remove" the last knob

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to `swap the two numbers` and put `[step]="-1"`

```
<mat-slider class="special" min="0" max="100" [step]="-1">
  <input value="40" matSliderStartThumb>
  <input value="30" matSliderEndThumb >
</mat-slider>
```