# mat-slider inverting active and inactive tracks

Tags: angular-material, mat-slider

I am using angular Material 15.
Is there a way to make so the active track (the thick one) is on the right side of the thumb instead of the left side?

[image]

I havn,'t found anything in the documentation.
And besides playing with ::ng-deep on several of the nested classes in mat-slider, I have not been able to change the active track side.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I invert the track of the slider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75720182/how-can-i-invert-the-track-of-the-slider)